# Conditional select on view

Tags: sql, t-sql, view

I have a view in my database (`MSSQL`) that takes more than 1 minute to output results. Since this is taking this long, I gave the user the ability to either see live data or cached data. I do this by generating the data from the view and inserting it into a table hourly and by defining a config variable on use_cached = 0 or 1.

Lets say the view is called v_foo and the cache table is called t_bar. I want to create another view that selects from v_foo if `use_cached = 0` and select from t_bar if `use_cached = 1.`

I tried something like

```
Create view v_final as 
select * from v_foo
where (select count(*) from config where id = 'use_cache' and value = 1) = 0
UNION ALL
select * from t_bar
where (select count(*) from config where id = 'use_cache' and value = 1) = 1
```

But this causes both queries from the union all to be always calculated even if one of them does not return any rows.
Using a function is also a not so good solution because in order to return a table using IF conditions, I must declare a temporary table and just populating it is taking almost 17 seconds.

Any Help?

Comment: Before jumping through hoops like this, I'd take a closer look at `v_foo`. I suspect there are some tuning opportunities there.

Comment: can you show us the definitions of the 2 views you select from ?

Comment: If you insist on using a view, I think you could have it select from a table-valued function that contains the if/then logic.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can use stored procedure with this code:

```
if (exists (select * from config where id = 'use_cache' and value = 1))
    select * from t_bar
else
    select * from v_foo
```